# Loading image in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**EDIT**

I have a upload result action, it can take minutes for returning a new page. I want to set in a div or something a loading image.

I don't know why but i get the feeling this is not the right way. What is the right way to show a loading screen/add loading image in ASP.NET.

I have this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadTarget(UploadViewModel model)
      {
    //code that takes minutes
    return RedirectToAction("UploadSuccess", "Upload");
    }
```

How can i trigger a function before it begins run the uploadtarget function.

```
<script>
    function wait() {
       document.getElementById("wait").innerHTML = '<img src="/Images/wait.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> ';
    }
</script>

<div class="col-md-6">
     @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadActual", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remark)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Remark)
           <input onclick="wait()"type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-   primary btn-lg"/>
}
</div>

<div id="wait"class="col-md-6"></div>
```

It runs my javascript function after the RedirectToaction. So it does nothing anymore. How can i fix this? with c# or javascript? Or is there a other good solution?

Comment: You need to supply more details. what is the errors ?

Comment: You doing a standard post upload or async upload? Are there even errors or do you just need an indicator to show it posted? And what do you mean by "this doesn't work well?"

Comment: with that javascript i think it is running the uploadTarget frist after that it runs showWait(). so i think to the next possible solution with RedirectToactions with uploadviewmodel as parameter

Comment: A little more information, or code example, would help us help you. It's tough to see what you are doing from just this. For instance, is this onClick on a submit button that posts the form with a file input in it?

Comment: i have add more information

Comment: How do you hit UploadTarget when the form is using the UploadActual action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display the image right away and then submit the form on timeout, to give image time to display. Something like this:

```
function wait() {
   document.getElementById("wait").innerHTML = '<img src="/Images/wait.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> ';
   setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("myForm").submit()},10);
}

<input onclick="wait()"type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-   primary btn-lg"/>
```

Where "myForm" is ID of your form.